# How Django to Hot Reload Uwsgi every workers Singleton value?

Tags: django, uwsgi

I want to hot reload my server, I have a Singleton Object, I want to change some value and become effective to each workers.

I try to use open an api to access my edit, but It only refresh "that" workers singleton, the other is same the old one

Is there has anyway can guide me? like

```
@uwsgidecorators.postfork
```

but It just suit for start workers.

example:

```
@singleton
class A:
      value = get_from_redis()
   def set_value(self):
        self.value = 321
   def get_value(self):
        return self.value
```

my uwsgi.ini

```
processes = 4
```

when I call my api

```
 def get(self, requests, format=None):
      A().set_value()
```

Then My 4 process only 1 value is set to 321 but the other is 123

Comment: If you need to share data between workers you need to store it externally in a shared store, eg memcached or redis.

Comment: considering performance, I already that my data into redis, I already update, the data is very big, so I just use like static way to assign first.